# What's the differences btw const_get and qualified_const_get?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

There is a series of methods, i.e., const_defined?, const_get, or const_set, in standard ruby library.

`const_defined?,
const_get,
const_set`

And also, in the Active Support Core Extensions of Rails, their "qualified_" counterparts for these individuals exist.

`qualified_const_defined?,
qualified_const_get,
qualifeid_const_set`

Is there anybody who can explain explicitly the differences between bare and qualified forms for these methods?

Thank you in advance.

Hyo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `qualified_` const helpers support interacting with constants at arbitrary depths (not just children of the subject).

I think an example is the easiest way to explain this one.  Let's say `Foo::Bar::Baz` exists:

```
 > Object::const_get "Foo::Bar::Baz"
NameError: wrong constant name Foo::Bar::Baz
 > Object::const_get "Foo"
=> Foo
 > Foo.const_get "Bar"
=> Foo::Bar
 > Foo::Bar.const_get "Baz"
=> Foo::Bar::Baz
```

The `qualified_` methods allow you to avoid walking the module hierarchy directly:

```
 > Object::qualified_const_get "Foo::Bar::Baz"
=> Foo::Bar::Baz
 > Foo.qualified_const_set "Bar::Fizz", 123
=> 123
 > Foo::Bar::Fizz
=> 123
```

[I'd recommend poking around the source, too](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/11f6795b238172c4a13176062bd38b83285799b7/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/qualified_const.rb).  It's pretty clean.

Comment: In other words, one is for getting namespace-qualified constants.

Comment: What's the differences between Object::const_get and Object.const_get?

Comment: In my case(ruby 2.0), Object::const_get "Foo::Bar::Baz" and Object::qualified_const_get "Foo::Bar::Baz" show the same results without NameError ; "Foo::Bar::Baz".

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't realize that they added support for that to `const_get` in 2.0.  Nice.

Comment: @lioncat no difference between those two statements

Comment: @Nevir. Finally, do you mean there is no difference between const_get and qualified_const_get in Ruby 2.0? Still, it seems I don't know the real difference between these guys. I need some more explanations.

Comment: @lioncat oh sorry, I was referring to `Object::const_get` vs `Object.const_get` - in that context, they're identical

Comment: But yeah, it looks like Ruby 2.0 changed the behavior of `const_get` to support qualified constant lookups, whereas 1.9.3 and below do not

Comment: @Nevir, Thank you so much. Your last comment resolved my situation.

Answer (score 0):

you might find this interesting:

http://redcorundum.blogspot.com/2006/05/kernelqualifiedconstget.html