# Debugging Object.const_get

Tags: ruby, dynamic

Consider the following code (I know I have for the past 30 minutes):

```
[1] pry(main)> DurhamScraper::Tweet
=> DurhamScraper::Tweet
[2] pry(main)> Object.const_get("DurhamScraper::Tweet")
NameError: wrong constant name DurhamScraper::Tweet
from (pry):2:in 'const_get'
[3] pry(main)> String
=> String
[4] pry(main)> Object.const_get("String")
=> String
```

`DurhamScraper::Tweet` is a class that is loaded properly (as you can infer from line 1). No exceptions were raised when I ran the code earlier. The only change from when the code executed properly is that I changed the repository name. Any advice on how to debug further, or how I may solve for this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071168/whats-the-differences-btw-const-get-and-qualified-const-get. Use `qualified_const_get` (if you have access to ActiveSupport), or walk the hierarchy: `Object.const_get('DurhamScraper').const_get('Tweet')`.

Comment: I don't have access to ActiveSupport but walking the hierarchy does the trick. I'm frustrated though because plain ol' `const_get` worked just fine before renaming the repo.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you on?

Comment: BOOM! renaming the repo was somewhat of a red herring...my machine defaults to 1.9.3 (for work). Setting to 2.1.1 did the trick. Thanks! @kardiez - I suggest writing an answer that combines your two comments for debugging (check Ruby version, walk hierarchy), and I'll go ahead and accept it.

Comment: Are .ruby_version files idiomatic? I feel like I don't see them often, but it would prevent these types of issues, no?

Comment: I don't think they have any official capacity in Ruby, but both rbenv and RVM respect them; I've found them to be useful.

Comment: Please, just read the error message: `Module#const_get` takes a constant name, and `Durhamscraper::Tweet` is simply not a valid name for a constant. A constant is an identifier that starts with a capital letter, and `:` is a character that is not allowed in an identifier.

Comment: Per Ruby 2.1.1 documentation:  _This method will recursively look up constant names if a namespaced class name is provided._ The issue was that when I changed the directory's name, I was no longer using Ruby 2.1.1 and was instead using Ruby 1.9.3, which supports the behavior you described.  I appreciate that you may be trying to help, but this is a community forum, and condescension ("Please, just read...") has no place here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Ruby 2.1.1 documentation: *This method will recursively look up constant names if a namespaced class name is provided.*

The issue was that when I changed the directory's name, I was no longer using Ruby 2.1.1 and was instead using Ruby 1.9.3. If `Object.const_get` does not work as you expect, make sure to check the Ruby version and the corresponding documentation.

For earlier versions of Ruby that do not allow for namespaced class names, you can walk the hierarchy, as kardeiz suggested:

```
Object.const_get(NAMESPACE).const_get(CLASS)
```